# How to test webhook/notifications for "On Hold" transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have application that have paypal payments in production. But one of the transaction currently in status "On Hold", our webhook history show that paypal send us "APPROVED" transaction but there's no incoming webhook that showing reasons it changed to "On Hold".

any help/guide on which specific webhook should I enable? Currently confirmed there's no disputes raised, so i'm stuck on how my end can know this "On Hold" status updates[image: sample on hold payment]

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to all webhook event names (*) , and log all events received.

Comment: yes technically i could enable all webhook event names but I also need to prepare a handler for that. Do you know how to replicate this in Sandbox env?

Comment: It would depend in part on the reason for the hold. The point is to enable all events, log them, then write the handler.